# MS-Word wildcards: How to find texts that match either of two strings

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, wildcards

I wanna find `am` or `pm` in a MS-Word document. I've tried all these wildcard expressions, but none of them works:
[am|pm]
[(am)|(pm)]
(am)|(pm)

Comment: Have you tried `am|pm`, no parenthesis, no square brackets ?

Comment: Use [ap]m pattern. OR does not exist in MS Word wildcards - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607800/microsoft-word-regex-is-there-an-or-operator-such-as

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for AM and PM as designators of time. This wildcard criteria works for that purpose.

```
[0-9][ ]<[AaPp][Mm]>
```